# Three.js / WebGL How to mirror one side of a texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

I'm basically trying to achieve a kaleidoscopic effect with just one side, but I'm working with lots of Points, so I'd like that to happen in the shader. However if there's a Threejs trick that mirrors half of the texture or the Points object, that would be great. I tried to apply transformation matrices but I can't get it to work.

I found an old [KaleidoShader](https://github.com/mistic100/three.js-examples/blob/master/examples/js/shaders/KaleidoShader.js) that requires the usage of EffectComposer, but I'd like to implement it manually myself (without EffectComposer) and I'm struggling to do so. I'm using an FBO and I tried adding the code from that shader in both my simulation and render shaders but it's having no effect at all. Do I have to add yet another FBO texture or is it possibile to do those calculations in one of the existing shaders?

For visual reference https://ma-hub.imgix.net/wp-images/2019/01/23205110/premiere-pro-mirror-effect.jpg

I've spent so much time without getting to the bottom of this, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just followed [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-post-processing.html)

Pasting in the code from that repo seems to work

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/build/three.module.js';
import {EffectComposer} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js';
import {RenderPass} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass.js';
import {ShaderPass} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/examples/jsm/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js';
import {GUI} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/../3rdparty/dat.gui.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 2;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  function makeInstance(geometry, color, x) {
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color});

    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    cube.position.x = x;

    return cube;
  }

  const cubes = [
    makeInstance(geometry, 0x44aa88,  0),
    makeInstance(geometry, 0x8844aa, -2),
    makeInstance(geometry, 0xaa8844,  2),
  ];

  const composer = new EffectComposer(renderer);
  composer.addPass(new RenderPass(scene, camera));

  // from:
  // https://github.com/mistic100/three.js-examples/blob/master/LICENSE
  const  kaleidoscopeShader = {
    uniforms: {

      "tDiffuse": { value: null },
      "sides":    { value: 6.0 },
      "angle":    { value: 0.0 }

    },

    vertexShader: `

      varying vec2 vUv;

      void main() {

        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

      }

    `,

    fragmentShader: `

      uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
      uniform float sides;
      uniform float angle;
      
      varying vec2 vUv;

      void main() {

        vec2 p = vUv - 0.5;
        float r = length(p);
        float a = atan(p.y, p.x) + angle;
        float tau = 2. * 3.1416 ;
        a = mod(a, tau/sides);
        a = abs(a - tau/sides/2.) ;
        p = r * vec2(cos(a), sin(a));
        vec4 color = texture2D(tDiffuse, p + 0.5);
        gl_FragColor = color;

      }
    `
  };


  const kaleidoscopePass = new ShaderPass(kaleidoscopeShader);
  kaleidoscopePass.renderToScreen = true;
  composer.addPass(kaleidoscopePass);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  const gui = new GUI();
  gui.add(kaleidoscopePass.uniforms.sides, 'value', 0, 20).name('sides');
  gui.add(kaleidoscopePass.uniforms.angle, 'value', 0, 6.28, 0.01).name('angle');
  
  let then = 0;
  function render(now) {
    now *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds
    const deltaTime = now - then;
    then = now;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      composer.setSize(canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    cubes.forEach((cube, ndx) => {
      const speed = 1 + ndx * .1;
      const rot = now * speed;
      cube.rotation.x = rot;
      cube.rotation.y = rot;
    });

    composer.render(deltaTime);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, I appreciate your help! That's the shader I was trying to implement – and I was able to integrate your example in my code and it pretty much does the trick, with the added flexibility of being able to add more sides and to play around with the angles. I wanted to avoid using EffectComposer and to add all the code in my existing shaders, as more of a challenge than a necessity (also guessing it's more efficient?), and I'll keep trying to achieve that and see if it's possible without another rendering pass.

Comment: Of course if you want to do it from scratch you may end up reproducing much of the code in EffectComposer. At a minimum you'll need to create a [RenderTarget](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-rendertargets.html). Render your scene into that target then render with another scene using a plane and the kaleidoscope shader and passing in the texture from the render target.

Comment: I will give that a go, thanks again! marking your answer as the solution

Answer (score 1):

There is a texture wrap mode that does mirroring.

texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping

Does that help?

edit: Here's an example showing mirroredrepeatwrapping on both axis:

https://glitch.com/~three-mirroredrepeatwrapping

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have any effect when I initialize it like this 
            var texture = new THREE.DataTexture(
                data, width, height, THREE.RGBFormat, THREE.FloatType, THREE.DEFAULT_MAPPING, THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping, THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping
                );

Comment: is there some code or a fiddle showing how this wrapping works? I am only seeing it in the docs, but not achieve my specific purpose.

Comment: thank you, I will look into it and try to replicate. I am working this kind of geometry https://rawgit.com/nicoptere/FBO/master/noise.html and I haven't found a way to immediately – perhaps it doesn't work with a ShaderMaterial and DataTexture. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It should work with all texture types as far as I know. You have to read texture coordinates outside of 0 to 1 range to get to the flipped version though, but the clamping/wrap modes are part of the webgl texture API so it should work.